# ошибка во время компиляции busybox

Tags: linux

```
root@ali-AN515-44:/home/ali/manticore_kernel/busybox# make CONFIG_PREFIX=/distro install

miscutils/devfsd.c: In function ‘action_execute’:
miscutils/devfsd.c:857:57: error: ‘%s’ directive output may be truncated writing up to 1023 bytes into a region of size 254 [-Werror=format-truncation=]
  857 |  snprintf(gv_info.devpath, sizeof(gv_info.devpath), "%s/%s", mount_point, info->devname);
      |                                                         ^~
miscutils/devfsd.c:857:2: note: ‘snprintf’ output 2 or more bytes (assuming 1025) into a destination of size 255
  857 |  snprintf(gv_info.devpath, sizeof(gv_info.devpath), "%s/%s", mount_point, info->devname);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
miscutils/devfsd.c: In function ‘action_copy’:
miscutils/devfsd.c:895:57: error: ‘%s’ directive output may be truncated writing up to 1023 bytes into a region of size 254 [-Werror=format-truncation=]
  895 |  snprintf(gv_info.devpath, sizeof(gv_info.devpath), "%s/%s", mount_point, info->devname);
      |                                                         ^~
miscutils/devfsd.c:895:2: note: ‘snprintf’ output 2 or more bytes (assuming 1025) into a destination of size 255
  895 |  snprintf(gv_info.devpath, sizeof(gv_info.devpath), "%s/%s", mount_point, info->devname);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:198: miscutils/devfsd.o] Ошибка 1
```

Comment: Видимо по какой то причине у Вас включился `-Werror=format-truncation=` (например, потому что было добавлено `-Wall`). А в самом коде просто пытаются впихнуть большую строку в маленькую и это не получится. Да, наверно обычно там все будет ок, но оставим это на совести разработчиков BusyBox

Comment: а ну окей, мне надо просто пропустить это?

Comment: Вам нужно понять, почему это произошло. То есть, кто выставил эту опцию компиляции

Comment: а все понял, сейчас заново создам конфиг для сборки

Comment: config WERROR
 bool "Abort compilation on any warning"
 default n
 help
 This adds -Werror to gcc command line.

 Most people should answer N.

Comment: этот кусок в Config.in удалить?

Comment: не нужно удалять кусок конфига. перезапустите генерацию конфига

Comment: если не трудно, то могли бы показать как перезапустить генерацию конфига?

Comment: в файле INSTALL описано -   `make defconfig
&&  make menuconfig`